# GoLand IDE doesn't put project into workspace during checkout from VCS

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, goland

If I create project from scratch, GoLand pay attention to my workspace and put project correct according to $GOPATH.

For example I have GOPATH: *$HOME/{user}/go*, so GoLand put it into :

```
$HOME/{user}/go/src/{myproject}
```

But if I try to checkout from VCS it puts into **GoLandProjects** directory:

```
$HOME/GoLandProjects/{myproject}
```

Is it possible to change that behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the directory where the checkout is done right in the checkout dialog, see below.[image: vsc checkout dialog]

After the first checkout, the IDE will remember where to do the next one, as it's shown in my case and it will suggest something similar.

However, with the rise of vgo as a dependency management tool, this will not be required anymore as the GOPATH will stop being mandatory.

Comment: Yes, first time you have to do it manually, please feel free to create a ticket if you want this changed somehow: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go

Comment: thank you for your response. maybe I just used to Intellij IDEA java behaviour

Comment: I looked a bit more on our tracker and found this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-4770 Unfortunately, it doesn't look like a popular request but it doesn't have to be in order to be implemented. I'll add a note about this question there.